# How to treat NA values when using apply function?

Tags: r, matrix, apply, na

I think my problem is very simple.
I want to get aaa matrix data, including NA values, calculated from array data.
For solving, unfortunately, I used for loop, and too many lost my time. Actually, my data is too huge.
So, I want to solve this problem using functions like apply.

```
a1 <- matrix(c(NA, 1:5), 3, 2)
a2 <- a1
a3 <- matrix(NA, 3, 2)
a4 <- a1

b <- array(c(a1, a2, a3, a4), c(3, 2, 4))

#
A <- apply(b, c(1,2), min, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: Actually you get the desired cell minimums disregarding NA's. If there are only NA's, Inf is yielded and you get a friendly warning. Use `replace(A, is.infinite(A), NA)` to replace them with NA if that's what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it ok to ignore the error that occurs here? Finally, I want to save these calculated values as raster data.

Comment: It's a warning which is different from an error. Try `as.raster(replace(A, is.infinite(A), NA))`, you need values between 0 and 1 in your array though.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved the problem.